# Flutter esc_pos_printer library for thermal printers (LAN based)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, thermal-printer

I have been using [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer) in my project up to now. There has been no update on it and because of this my entire codebase is sitting in the past without updates. Does anyone know of any alternative reliable library for LAN based thermal printers? or any paid alternative for thermal printers? Please this is affecting a lot of people and the proof is on their [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_printer/issues).

Comment: For example, there is such an example, but isn't it much different? [andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_utils](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_utils/issues), [marcusfelix/esc-pos-printer-flutter](https://github.com/marcusfelix/esc-pos-printer-flutter/issues)

Comment: Same thing, no updates, is there nothing inbuilt in flutter for these things?

Comment: Find out if there is really anything on the market. For example, if the demand for printing applications is increasing, then perhaps closed usage is increasing in commercial products. Or if the number of applications is increasing but the purpose of printing is not increasing, or if the number of applications themselves is not increasing, the current trend may not be suitable for printing.